# I want to replace multy line string with sed or perl

Tags: perl, sed

I want to delete:

```
         ,
.rdt(rdt)
```

from text:

```
.colldisn(1'b0),
.rdt(rdt)
```

while `.colldisn`  could be various texts.

So, I have a lot of file with this substring and I want to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/,\s*\n\s*\.rdt(rdt)//;P;D' file
```

If you want to preserve the space and newline:

```
sed '$!N;s/,\(\s*\n\s*\)\.rdt(rdt)/\1/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/,\n.rdt(rdt)//g' tst.txt
```

Where the `tst.txt` is you file, to write to the same file don't forget to add the `-i` option.

The `:a;N;$!ba;` will let you to accomplish what you want, witch is to compare several lines.

Comment: are you running this in shell or in a file?

Comment: shell on multiple files

Comment: Can you please post the command you are trying to use, and remember that if you are running a perl script you need to escape some chars, making something like this:
 `\`sed -e ':a;N;\$!ba;s/,\\n.rdt(rdt)//g' tst.txt\``

Comment: sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/,\n.rdt(rdt)//g' *
ba: Event not found.

Comment: lets try something a bit different: `sed -e 'N;s/,\n.rdt(rdt)//g;P;D' *`, changing a bit the @potong script

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy in Perl: just keep the previous line in a variable. If you encounter `.rdt(rdt)`, check that the previous line ends in a comma. If so, print the previous line without the comma and forget the current line, otherwise print the whole previous line. Do not forget to output the last line at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

myscript:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak

undef $/;                   # get all the text
while(<>){ 
  s/,\n\.rdt\(rdt\)//g; 
  print;
}
```

the "-i.bak" changes de original "file" but creates a "file.bak" copy.
This way you can use

```
myscript *.txt
```

to change all txt files in current dir.
A similar switch exists for sed.